# Is AT91 devices in atmel studio?

Tags: microcontroller, arm, atmel, atmel-studio

I want to make a new project with AT91SAM9260 in Atmel Studio 7 but it doesn't support the device.

My question is:

Did Atmel make a C library with this device to Atmel Studio 7? If no, what version does this device have ?

Comment: In my version of Atmel Studio 7 (7.0.1006) I see this device (File -> New -> Atmel Start Project: Select device and go on).

Comment: Aw, sorry not this, I wanted to write AT91SAM9260

Comment: I think it should support it. If I remember correctly, when you install Atmel Studio it will ask you what you want it to support: 8-bit AVR, 32-bit AVR, and SMART ARM. Do you remember checking the last one?

Comment: @DigitalNinja I checket all

Comment: @Sewek It looks like it is not supported, it's not in the list of devices.  http://www.atmel.com/tools/atmelstudio.aspx?tab=devices. But if you read through the documentation for the device, it will probably help you get setup. You'll just need some other ARM toolchain. http://www.yagarto.org/

Comment: @DigitalNinja Thanks and from which version of atmel studio supports the AT91SAM9260?

Comment: @Sewek I'm not sure. Maybe none of them. You will have to research it. Look through the device's documentation, look at the older IDE version release notes. I'm not doing all of that for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a library made by ATMEL. I looked it up from KEIL'S uVision IDE and this [webpage](http://www.keil.com/dd/docs/arm/atmel/sam9260/at91sam9260.h). I also could not find support for ATMEL Studio 7.